# Python - Erro na Mongo Engine, Erro: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (Duplicate Key Error)

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

Python estou tentando salvar mais de um usuário no Json mas ele não aceita a introdução de mais de um, sempre dá o:

> Tried to save duplicate unique keys (Duplicate Key Error)

aqui está o código:

```
from .model import User, UserSchema
from flask import Blueprint, request
from flask import jsonify

schema = UserSchema()
api = Blueprint('users', __name__)

@api.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def create():
    # Pegar os dados da requisição
    user_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    if not user_json:
        return "FAIL"

    # Criar uma entidade a partir do JSON
    user, errors = schema.load(user_json)
    if bool(errors):
        return jsonify(errors)
    user.save()
    return "SUCCESS"

@api.route('/', methods=['PATCH'])
def update():
    # Pegar os dados da requisição
    user_json = request.get_json()
    user = User.objects(name=user_json['name']).first()
    schema.update(user, user_json)
    user.save()
    return "SUCESS"

@api.route('/auth', methods=['POST'])
def auth():
    # cria a senha 
    user_json = request.get_json()
    if not user_json:
        return "FAIL"

    user = User.objects(name = user_json['name']).first()
    if not user:
        return "FAIL"
    if user.password == user_json['password']:
        user.save()
        return "SUCCESS"
    else:
        return "FAIL"

@api.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def list():
    # Retorna os usuários do JSON
    list_users = []
    for user in User.objects():
        list_users.append(schema.dump(user))
    return jsonify(list_users)
```

Comment: Creio que o problema é devido ao formato do json enviado em `user_json = request.get_json()`, provavelmente tem IDs repetidas ou não tem IDs definidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido, foi descoberto que eu haviam duas variáveis:

name = StringField(unique=True)
password = StringField(unique=True)

trocamos para required e funcionou.

Obrigamos pela atenção de quem tentou ajudar :D